# PHPMailer HTML, Plain Text, Content Types, etc

Tags: email, phpmailer

I'm new to PHPMailer and I can't seem to find a clear answer to this seemingly common question in the examples/docs. on Github.

My understanding is that PHPMailer can somehow automatically set the mime content-type to `multipart/alternative` if the recipient's email client doesn't render HTML emails.

Would that be done by just setting `$mail->AltBody` like this (below)?

```
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
```

Additionally, should I be using `msgHTML()` if I have HTML content?  And how does `$mail->isHTML(true);` factor in here?

Basically, how should I specify to PHPMailer that I want it to show the HTML content if the reader can see it, but otherwise fall back to plain text if they don't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do what the examples do. Call `isHTML()`, then put your HTML in `Body` and your plain text in `AltBody`. It uses those to build a proper multipart/alternative MIME structure. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Synchro.  In a bit of experimentation, I left out the `isHTML()` part and supplied a `$mail->Body` and a `$mail->AltBody` and it seemed to still yield a multipart/alternative email.  Is it even necessary?

Comment: Side note: I've been working with a developer for an open source user management system called "UserSpice" and the only way we can get SMTP mail to be sent is by commenting out `$mail->isSMTP();`.  If that is active, it all fails.  Seems odd though since that's what's supposed to be telling the program to use SMTP.  Thoughts?

Comment: If you comment that out, you’re not using SMTP; you’re using PHP’s mail function. To find out why SMTP isn’t working for you, read the troubleshooting guide.

Comment: Would there be some indication in the headers of the emails being sent that it was sent via SMTP vs. PHP's mail() function?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes - look at the `Received` headers. You will also be able to see it in your local mail server logs.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Regarding my original question though and first comment to your answer: I left out the `isHTML()` part and supplied a `$mail->Body` and a `$mail->AltBody` and it seemed to still yield a multipart/alternative email. Is `isHTML()` even necessary?

Comment: No, `isHTML` is not necessary - it's assumed automatically if `AltBody` is non-empty. Makes your code clearer though!